# Round corners using custom images

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a box with round corners using images. I know how to use CSS3 but I need to use images as I have some custom made corners with shadow and transparency.

The result I need:

[image]

I have divided the box into several images:

http://i37.tinypic.com/2w6b14g_th.png

I know there is plenty of info about this topic, but I have been working with this for the last days and from the articles I've read I cannot get exactly what I need. The problem seems to be that I need the background of all images to have a some transparency (both the white part and the shadow part). Anyone has an idea on how to do this using `divs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favorite technique is this one: [even more rounded corners](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/even-more-rounded-corners/). Look at the demo page: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/dialog2/. It does exactly what you want.

Plus, unlike other techniques, you don't have to cut up your background image.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with rounded corners in this way today. I'm using GIF's which have the corners in the colour of the background. Because these are GIF's the corners could be transparent, but I'd rather not worry about what's 'behind'. But in your situation a GIF would be better than a JPG(is this what you are doing?), as transparency is supported, or a PNG if you don't need to support old browsers. Then you can put the background colour in the style for the DIV is you want too.

HTH

Comment: I'm using png to do this. And the problem is that I need the background of the images I use to be transparent not a solid color like in the examples I've seen. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: It depends what program you are using to edit the image.Gimp is easy for transparency just select the areas with the wand and hit delete. What are you using to create the image? What image editors do you have available?

Comment: Here is a page that references PNG and DIV's for opacity/transparency:

http://virtuelvis.com/gallery/opacity/opacitydemo.html

This may be more like what you are after